# Search and replace for VS Code using regex (enclosed pattern)

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to replace texts using regex using vscode.

How do I do it if it is an enclosed pattern below?

```
from:
<script src="../../app-assets/js/app.js">

to:
<script src="{% static 'app-assets/js/app.js' %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for this regex (notice the capture group around the path):

```
\<script src="\.\.\/\.\.\/(app-assets\/js\/app\.js)"\>
```

and then replace it with:

```
<script src="{% static '$1' %}">
```

Where `$1` references the 1st captured group.